# Grails app: JS files obfuscation

Tags: grails, ant, war, google-closure-compiler

I would like to replace js files with their minimized versions (minimized by Closure Compiler - https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) in war file. To build war I'm using ant:

```
...
<target name="war" depends="buildnumber" description="--> Creates a WAR of a Grails application">
    <grails command="war" environment="${grails.env}"/>
</target>
...
```

I added:

```
grails.project.resources = { stagingDir ->
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/js/*.js")
}
```

to <root>\grails-app\conf\BuildConfig.groovy but js files are not removed for war file.

How can I provide the list of files to minimize in ant build file, and how to add it to final war file?

UPDATED:

I added following to \grails-app\conf\BuildConfig.groovy to copy minimized files to war file. In first step ant minimizes js files. In next step war file is produced, and this step replaces original js files with minimized files.

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    def jsFiles = [
            'file1.js',
            'file2.js',
            'file3.js',
            ...
            'templates.common.js'
    ];
    for (file in jsFiles) {
        File f = new File("minimizedjs\\${file}");
        if(f.exists()) {
            copy(file: "minimizedjs\\${file}", tofile: "${stagingDir}\\js\\${file}")
        }
        else {
            println('.....!');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look at the [resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) with [yui-minify-resources](http://grails.org/plugin/yui-minify-resources).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a plugin for that - http://grails.org/plugin/closure-compiler - so there's no need for a manual process using Ant.

Answer (score 4):

Burt Beckwith's answer is the correct one.

Here's the specific reasons why your solution doesn't work though:

- It should be `grails.war.resources`. not `grails.project.resources`: see the [Manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/deployment.html)
- To use wildcards in ant, use a `fileset` tag instead of a `file` attribute

Here's a fixed version that should work:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    delete() {
        fileset(dir:"${stagingDir}/js", includes: "*.js")
    }
}
```